# In Looker Studio, how can I create a calculated metric for sessions that included visiting Page X and Page Y?

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I am trying to calculate:

```
Value 1: total sessions that viewed page X
Value 2: sessions that viewed page X and page Y
End goal: Value2/Value1 as a percentage
```

My problem is ultimately finding out what value 2 is. Even with calculated fields, I can't seem to to isolate sessions that included viewing two pages.

I've tried different filters, but none seem to work and give no data. I've reviewed the way to write a formula for a calculated field but can't see anything on identifying commonalities in single sessions.

Maybe there's a way to write a formula I don't know, but I'd also appreciate confirmation that this can't be done.